# Python 3.8 resolve import paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Till Python 3.7, whenever I had a package (eg: `mypackage`) both in `site-packages` and in a directory specified as `PYTHONPAH`, importing it would result in Python loading it from the PYTHOPATH dir.

For instance, with the following directories

```
/site-packages
    ...
    mypackage
    ...

/somedir
    /mylibraries
        ...
        mypackage
        ...
```

and setting `PYTHONPATH=/somedir/mylibraries`, the following code would import it `/somedir/mylibraries`

```
import sys
print(sys.path) # [..., '/somedir/mylibraries' ,...]

import mypackage
print(mypackage.__path__) # '/somedir/mylibraries/mypackage'
```

After upgrading to Python 3.8, some major about path resolution seems to be changed:

```
import sys
print(sys.path) # [..., '/somedir/mylibraries' ,...]

import mypackage
print(mypackage.__path__) # '.../site-packages/mypackage'
```

How to import libraries from the PYTHONPAH in Python 3.8?

Comment: Where does the ``site-packages`` occur in ``sys.path`` relative to ``/somedir/mylibraries``?

Comment: After it (first /somedir/mylibraries and THEN site-packages)

Comment: And that is the case on both Python 3.7 and 3.8?

Comment: I don't have the python 3.7 env at hand because we switched over to 3.8